# strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given even though it is definitely a string

Tags: php, yii2

```
public function getImages( $images )
{
    $ids = [];
    //\Kint::dump( $images['file'][0]['name'] );
    foreach( $images['file'] as $image ){


        $url = $image['url'];
        $name = $image['name'];


        if( strpos( strtolower( $name ) , 'jpg') !== false ){
            $assets = Asset::Find()
                ->filename( $name )
                ->all();
            if( count( $assets ) == 0 ){
                $ids [] = $this->createAssetFromUrl( $name, $url );
            }else{
                $ids [] = $assets[0]->id;
            }
        }

    }
    return $ids;
}
```

Hi im using this piece of code to get an images name from an array to determine whether it has already been downloaded or not however i keep getting this error

```
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
1. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vebraaltowrapper/src/services/VebraAltoWrapperService.php at line 441
    //\Kint::dump( $images['file'][0]['name'] );
    foreach( $images['file'] as $image ){


        $url = $image['url'];
        $name = $image['name'];

        //\Kint::dump( strpos( strtolower( $name ) , 'jpg') );

        if( strpos( strtolower( $name ) , 'jpg') !== false ){
            $assets = Asset::Find()
                ->filename( $name )
                ->all();
            if( count( $assets ) == 0 ){
                $ids [] = $this->createAssetFromUrl( $name, $url );
            }else{
                $ids [] = $assets[0]->id;
            }
        }
```

The error says that $name is an array however if i dump $name it clearly shows its a string

`$name string (12) "IMG_0693.JPG"`

so i though perhaps it was strpos() or strtolower() causing the issue but if i dump the full condition within the if statement like so
`\Kint::dump( strpos( strtolower( $name ) , 'jpg') );`
  it seems fine and returns exactly what i was expecting

`strpos(...) integer 9`

so the error only happens when that condition is put in an if statement, am i missing something obvious or is this a bug in php?

Comment: strange! have to try to cast your name var to string .. like `$name = (string)$image['name']`

Comment: Try to dump it under `$name = $image['name'];` and `die()` right **after** `foreach()` statement. (comment rest of code)

Comment: I find this commented line very strange: `//\Kint::dump( $images['file'][0]['name'] );` if this is the true structure of `$images` then it will be an array. Maybe try `foreach( $images['file'][0] as $image )`

Comment: what is $images? can you provide a dump for that?

Comment: Here is a dump for $images https://pastecode.xyz/view/c8853b7f

Comment: @LiamG, I thought the same thing. But looping though `$images` will assign `$images[0]` to `$image` the first time through the loop.

Comment: @MrGlass ah yes! of course, I feel so stupid!

Comment: If PHP thinks it is an array, it more than likely is... have you tried `var_dump($name)` ?

Comment: @LiamG var_dump($name) returns string(12) "IMG_0693.JPG" and typecasting it (string)$name throws an array to string conversion error

Comment: @Luca, what is your environment (PHP ver, OS, web server)? Also, do you have any uncommon extensions loaded?

Comment: @LiamG, no worries, LiamG. I was typing something very similar when I caught myself ;-)

Comment: Does strpos($name , 'jpg') return the same error? Or try with strpos(strtoupper($name) , 'JPG') to see what happens.

Comment: @MrGlass my apache version is Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/7.1.14 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 and OS is macOS high sierra no uncommon extensions just the ones that come with XAMPP out the box

Comment: @Zhorov strpos($name , 'jpg') returns what it should do (false or location of substring) strpos(strtoupper($name) , 'JPG') returns the same error

Comment: are you manually creating the array `$images` or some form is submitted and you send the array to this function?